# Django/python: I want to loop over the fields in a form and display the values stored in the database

Tags: python, django, forms, models

Here is my models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    utype = models.ForeignKey(Usertype)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course, related_name='c+', blank=True)
    tutors = models.ManyToManyField(Course, related_name='t+', blank=True)
    account = models.IntegerField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    cellphone = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=14, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    credits = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    transactions = models.ManyToManyField(Transaction, related_name='t+', blank=True)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    paypalVerified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    applicationAccepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    apartment = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, null=True, blank=True)
    zip = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, null=True, blank=True)
```

Here is my forms.py:

```
class ContactInfoForm(ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ContactInfoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['cellphone'].label = "Cell Phone Number"
    self.fields['address'].label = "Address"
    self.fields['apartment'].label = "Apartment"
    self.fields['city'].label = "City"
    self.fields['state'].label = "State"
    self.fields['zip'].label = "Zip Code"
    self.fields['country'].label = "Country"
class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ('cellphone', 'address', 'apartment', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'country')
```

Here is my views.py:

```
def profile(request):
c=getUserContext(request)
c['contactInfoForm'] = ContactInfoForm(instance = c['profile'])
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.POST['formType'] == "ContactInfo":
        c['contactInfoForm'] = ContactInfoForm(request.POST, instance = c['profile'])
        if c['contactInfoForm'].is_valid():
            c['contactInfoForm'].save()
return render_to_response('profile.html', c)
```

If a user has entered data in all the fields in the ContactInfoForm, how do I loop over the fields in the form and display their values?

e.g. I want to display

Cell Phone Number   123-456-7890
Address 1 West Spring St
... etc.

I can't loop over the fields in my model because that includes many other fields that I do not want to display in the contactinfo section of the profile page.

I have been struggling on this for a while now and haven't gotten anywhere. If my question is not clear, please let me know and I will provide more information or try to restructure the question.

Here is how I am currently displaying the form to the user on profile.html:

```
{% for field in contactInfoForm %}
                    <tr>
                            <td class="fieldright">
                            <label class="inline">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {% if profile.field %}
                                    <div class="field">
                                        {{ profile.field }}
                                        <input type="hidden" name="{{ field }}" id="id_{{ field }}" value={{ profile.field }}>
                                    </div>
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ field }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </td>
                        </tr> 
                    {% endfor %}
```

EDIT: I changed profile.field to field.value and the value is being display now.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the fields of the form, not the fields of the model.

Comment: I thought that I was iterating over the fields of the form by doing {% for field in contactInfoForm %}

Comment: Do I have to do something like  {{ field.value }} to display the value?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide other fields just use exclude in your form than fields

```
 class Meta:
     model = UserProfile
     exclude = ('', '')
```